# Prisma - Sort by _sum

Tags: postgresql, prisma, prisma-graphql

I do have simple groupBy query in my prisma which looks like this:

```
const groupBy = await prisma.referral.groupBy({
  by: ['recommenderId'],
  _sum: {
     points: true,
  },
});
```

What I am looking for is the way to sort by this _sum value.

The current response is:

```
{
    "groupBy": [
        {
            "_sum": {
                "points": 20000
            },
            "recommenderId": 3
        },
        {
            "_sum": {
                "points": 19000
            },
            "recommenderId": 2
        },
        {
            "_sum": {
                "points": 34000
            },
            "recommenderId": 1
        }
    ]
}
```

What I need is to get is:

```
{
    "groupBy": [
        {
            "_sum": {
                "points": 34000
            },
            "recommenderId": 1
        },
        {
            "_sum": {
                "points": 20000
            },
            "recommenderId": 3
        },
        {
            "_sum": {
                "points": 19000
            },
            "recommenderId": 2
        },
    ]
}
```

Based on documentation (https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/filtering-and-sorting#sorting) I tried something like this:

```
const groupBy = await prisma.referral.groupBy({
      by: ['recommenderId'],
      _sum: {
        points: true,
      },
      orderBy: [
        {
          _sum: 'desc',
        },
      ],
    });
```

But with code I'm getting error:

> Argument _sum: Got invalid value 'desc' on prisma.groupByReferral.
> Provided String, expected ReferralSumOrderByAggregateInput

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `_sum` on different fields at the same time, so you also need to provide field name that you want to sort on:

```
const groupBy = await prisma.referral.groupBy({
      by: ['recommenderId'],
      _sum: {
        points: true,
      },
      orderBy: [
        {
          _sum: {
            // Add `points` key here
            points: 'desc'
          }
        },
      ],
    });
```

Comment: Hi @Danila, thank you for your answer. It seems like there needs to be also info in which way I want to sort. Currently getting an error: `Argument points: Provided value true of type Boolean on prisma.groupByReferral is not a enumTypes.
→ Possible values: SortOrder.asc, SortOrder.desc`

Comment: Replacing `points: true` in orderBy to `points: 'desc'` seems to fix the issue.

Comment: Oh, sure, sorry, it was a typo, yep it should be 'desc' or 'asc'